# Flux cluster notifications not showing which cluster an alert is coming from

Tags: kubernetes, devops, cluster-analysis

I am playing around with pushing notifications with flux on kubernetes. I have followed this guide https://fluxcd.io/docs/guides/notifications/ and so far I was able to make it send messages on slack. Right now the messages that we're receiving is `Dependencies do not meet ready condition, retrying in 30s`. Which I believe should be fine for now.

However, we're managing multiple clusters and now this could prove to be quite challenging to know which cluster an alert is coming from. Is there anyway to make it show which cluster an alert has been triggered and if so, how?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a spec.summary field where you can specify the cluster name and impact for alerts.

Please see the examples here: https://fluxcd.io/docs/components/notification/alert/#example

I've used the implementation:

```
spec:
summary: "Cluster - (cluster name here)"
```

to make it show which cluster an alert is coming from.